# Instantiating a list of object in a class of a module from within other modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, axon

I have two modules in a spring boot microservice project which uses Axon framework. in the first module that is defined as a core project to keep the models, I have two classes (User and Role) which User class contains a list of roles:

```
////// The User and Role classes are in the first module
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private boolean enabled = false;
    private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    private List<Role> roles;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

In the second module I have added the dependency of the first module in POM file in order to access the User and Role classes:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In the second module when I am trying to create a User object, it gets error and does not save the user to the event store and complains about the Role class and specifically the List of Role. the following is a controller class in the second module that is creating a User object to send to Axon:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/registerUser")
public class RegisterUserController {

private final CommandGateway commandGateway;
......

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody User user)
{
  Role role = new Role();
  role.setId(1);
  role.setName("Admin");
  
  List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
  roles.add(role);

  ....

  user.setRole(roles);

  RegisterUserCommand command = new RegisterUserCommand();
  command.setId(id);
  command.setUser(user);

  commandGateway.sendAndWait(command); /// Send the user to Axon

  ....  
}
```

**Important:** when I tried to have just one module and put the user and role classes, controllers and all things in that module, it worked with no problem.

Stacktarce:

```
2022-08-16 12:06:44.463  INFO 29816 --- [           main] c.h.user.cmd.api.UserCommandApplication  : Starting UserCommandApplication using Java 17.0.4 on DESKTOP-JUNLICE with PID 29816 (E:\Hawramgard_main\User_Management\user.cmd.api\target\classes started by Venos46131105 in E:\Hawramgard_main\User_Management)
2022-08-16 12:06:44.465  INFO 29816 --- [           main] c.h.user.cmd.api.UserCommandApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-16 12:06:45.249  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'org.axonframework.springboot.autoconfig.EventProcessingAutoConfiguration' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2022-08-16 12:06:45.360  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#4a1e3ac1#31' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.annotation.SpringContextParameterResolverFactoryBuilder$ClasspathParameterResolverFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.361  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#4a1e3ac1#31' of type [org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MultiParameterResolverFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.364  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#4a31c2ee#31' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.annotation.SpringBeanDependencyResolverFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.364  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#7be71476' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.annotation.SpringBeanParameterResolverFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.366  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '__axon-parameter-resolver-factory' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.ApplicationContextLookupParameterResolverFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.366  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '__axon-parameter-resolver-factory' of type [org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MultiParameterResolverFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.374  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#7b7683d4' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.annotation.SpringHandlerDefinitionBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.374  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#7b7683d4' of type [org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MultiHandlerDefinition] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.375  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#3efedc6f' of type [org.axonframework.spring.config.annotation.SpringHandlerEnhancerDefinitionBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.375  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#3efedc6f' of type [org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MultiHandlerEnhancerDefinition] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.376  INFO 29816 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '__axon-handler-definition' of type [org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MultiHandlerDefinition] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.653  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2022-08-16 12:06:45.667  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-16 12:06:45.667  INFO 29816 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-16 12:06:45.769  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-16 12:06:45.769  INFO 29816 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1265 ms
2022-08-16 12:06:45.977  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.s.a.XStreamAutoConfiguration         : Initializing an XStream instance since none was found. The auto configuration base packages will be used as wildcards for the XStream security settings.
2022-08-16 12:06:46.083  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.s.util.XStreamSecurityTypeUtility    : Constructing wildcard type for base package [com.hawramgard.user.cmd.api].
2022-08-16 12:06:46.091  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.serialization.ChainingConverter      : ContentTypeConverter of type [class org.axonframework.serialization.xml.Dom4JToByteArrayConverter] is ignored. It seems to rely on a class that is not available in the class loader: org/dom4j/Document
2022-08-16 12:06:46.091  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.serialization.ChainingConverter      : ContentTypeConverter of type [class org.axonframework.serialization.xml.InputStreamToDom4jConverter] is ignored. It seems to rely on a class that is not available in the class loader: org/dom4j/Document
2022-08-16 12:06:46.092  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.serialization.ChainingConverter      : ContentTypeConverter of type [class org.axonframework.serialization.xml.XomToStringConverter] is ignored. It seems to rely on a class that is not available in the class loader: nu/xom/Document
2022-08-16 12:06:46.092  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.a.serialization.ChainingConverter      : ContentTypeConverter of type [class org.axonframework.serialization.xml.InputStreamToXomConverter] is ignored. It seems to rely on a class that is not available in the class loader: nu/xom/ParsingException
2022-08-16 12:06:46.145  WARN 29816 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 


2022-08-16 12:06:46.309  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1ee5632d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@52a7928a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2f9dda71, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5fffb692, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@563ccd31, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@739831a4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@39023dbf, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7f5fcfe9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@67688110, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@72465eb2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6282b9f5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@79d7035, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2bab618]
2022-08-16 12:06:46.730  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Requesting connection details from localhost:8124
2022-08-16 12:06:47.147  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Successfully connected to localhost:8124
2022-08-16 12:06:47.158  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.connector.impl.ControlChannelImpl  : Connected instruction stream for context 'default'. Sending client identification
2022-08-16 12:06:47.170  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.command.impl.CommandChannelImpl  : CommandChannel for context 'default' connected, 0 command handlers registered
2022-08-16 12:06:47.174  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.command.impl.CommandChannelImpl  : Registered handler for command 'com.hawramgard.user.cmd.api.commands.RegisterUserCommand' in context 'default'
2022-08-16 12:06:47.179  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.command.impl.CommandChannelImpl  : Registered handler for command 'com.hawramgard.user.cmd.api.commands.RemoveUserCommand' in context 'default'
2022-08-16 12:06:47.180  INFO 29816 --- [           main] i.a.a.c.command.impl.CommandChannelImpl  : Registered handler for command 'com.hawramgard.user.cmd.api.commands.UpdateUserCommand' in context 'default'
2022-08-16 12:06:47.200  INFO 29816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-16 12:06:47.215  INFO 29816 --- [           main] c.h.user.cmd.api.UserCommandApplication  : Started UserCommandApplication in 3.056 seconds (JVM running for 5.815)
2022-08-16 12:07:13.096  INFO 29816 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 12:07:13.096  INFO 29816 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 12:07:13.096  INFO 29816 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
RegisterUserCommand(id=1638, user=com.hawramgard.user.core.models.User@7738b41d)
org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException: com.hawramgard.user.core.models.Role
```

Comment: I need to mention that, I changed the `private List<Role> roles` to `private Role role` in the User Class, and worked properly. But in case of List of objects, it has problems.

Comment: Hello @Pezhman! Could you share the exact error and stacktrace with me? That would help me pinpoint the issue. In addition, are you using Axon Server as well?

Comment: Thank you @Mitchell Herrijgers for your comment. Yes I'm using Axon server by using Docker.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see details about the error. However, I notice you are using Java17 and XStream, is that correct? XStream on Java 17 has a lot of issues. Can you try to use either an earlier Java version, or use the `JacksonSerializer`?

Comment: This is the exception: `org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException: com.hawramgard.user.core.models.Role`.  I'm not using XStream. The Java version is 17. Ok I'll try the earlier versions of java and JacksonSerializer.

Comment: It might be the defaultTyping option that you are missing then: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/serialization#default-typing

Comment: Where should I add this configuration in my project?

Comment: It should be in a `@Configuration` class and the method should be annotated with `@Bean`, then it will be picked up

Comment: Dear @Mitchell Herrijgers, the JacksonSerializer solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Great to hear! I added it as an answer for any users experiencing the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When Jackson needs to serialize a list, it loses the type information and is unable to deserialize it. This can be solved in Axon Framework using the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SerializerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Serializer jacksonSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return JacksonSerializer.builder()
                .defaultTyping()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Note that this can also be solved using `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation. For more information, see the javadoc of the `defaultTyping()` method on the `JacksonSerializer`:

> Configures the underlying ObjectMapper to include type information when serializing Java objects into JSON. Specifically, it calls ObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping) method, using ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS. This can be toggled on to allow java.util.Collections of objects, for example query java.util.List responses, to automatically include the types without require the use of com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo on the objects themselves.